# Render default image when image not found on server

Tags: javascript, image, iis-7

I have a web page which renders images from a server. If the image is not found, currently the IIS server returns 404 error and hence the image is not rendered.

I have a requirement to put a default image in case the image is not found on the server.

Can I make this setting on the IIS server so that it returns the default image for every invalid image requests?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery/Javascript to replace broken images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92720/jquery-javascript-to-replace-broken-images)

Comment: isn't there any IIS web.config rule that can be made?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the javascript onerror() event for images that are not found:

```
function imgError(image) {
        image.onerror = "";
        image.src = "somePlaceholderImage.gif";
        return true;
 }
```

then your images would be like this:

```
<img alt="some ALT text" src="http://someurlhere" onerror="imgError(this);">
```

Answer (score -1):

```
   <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="RewriteNoneExist">
                    <match url="\.(gif|jpe?g|png|bmp)"  ignoreCase="true" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="gfx/default.png" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
```